# Unable to mount 2nd 500 Gb USB hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, mount, ext3

I have two Seagate 500 GB USB hard drives.  I installed Debian 2.6.32-5-686 on one of them, and used dd to create a clone of the bootable drive.  I have verified that I can boot and run from either drive.  The format I used was ext3.

I would like to boot from one of them, and mount the other on a second USB port.  But I can't figure out how to get the 2nd drive to mount.

## Here's what fdisk returns for my system:

```
root@debian:/media# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 256 MB, 256901120 bytes
16 heads, 32 sectors/track, 980 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 512 * 512 = 262144 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x727232e1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         979      250608    b  W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009afe2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1       60046   482318336   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2           60047       60802     6065153    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5           60047       60802     6065152   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009afe2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           1       60046   482318336   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2           60047       60802     6065153    5  Extended
/dev/sdc5           60047       60802     6065152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

========================================

sda is a CF card (also bootable; I have DSL installed on it).

I created a subdirectory in mnt (debian 2) and tried to mount sdc:

```
root@debian:/media# mount -t auto -o uid=howard,gid=users /dev/sdc debian2
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Ok, since I know that the filesytem is ext3, I tried that:

```
root@debian:/media# mount -t ext3 -o uid=howard,gid=users /dev/sdc debian2
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
root@debian:/media# dmesg | tail
[ 3574.656384]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 < sdc5 >
[ 3574.755489] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3574.755501] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 4357.910378] VFS: Can't find ext3 filesystem on dev sdc.
[ 4398.311616] VFS: Can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev sdc.
[ 7765.840482] [drm] Big FIFO is disabled
[ 7766.124349] [drm] Big FIFO is disabled
[ 8490.172175] [drm] Big FIFO is disabled
[ 8490.172718] [drm] Big FIFO is disabled
[13344.805443] VFS: Can't find ext3 filesystem on dev sdc.
```

testdisk can see it:

```
Disk /dev/sdc - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 * Linux                    0  32 33 60045 250 45  964636672
 2 E extended             60046  28 13 60801  47 46   12130306
 5 L Linux Swap           60046  28 15 60801  47 46   12130304
```

When I went to analyze, I got this: EXT3 Large file Sparse superblock, 493 GB / 459 GiB

I have the same results regardless of which one I boot from (physically swapping & rebooting).

There should be a clue about what I'm doing wrong somewhere in there. I'm guessing (hoping) it's a n00bie mistake that's easy to fix.

TIA for any insight.

Comment: you cant mount /dev/sdc this would be the whole disk. try mounting /dev/sdc1 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mount the disk, you need to specify a partition #.

So for you it looks like it would be `/dev/sdc1`, the system figures out most of the rest by default.  So all you should need to type is:

> mount /dev/sdc1 /media/debian2

If you want that to happen on boot, you could add the drive to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @HowardLeeHarkness Great! Please be sure to accept an answer so people searching a similar issue in the future know it's been answered (whether that's mine or else isn't as huge a deal).

Answer (score 0):

*You must mount /dev/sdc1.* Also ensure that you have created the mountpoint where you want to access the disk.

the usual procedure in your case is:

> *mkdir /media/extern;  mount /dev/sdc1 /media/extern*

In Linux sdX stands for the actual hardrive and **sdX1, sdX2, sdX3, ...** and so on represent the actual partitions.

when it comes to physical harddrives linux does not allow you to mount a complete disk. you always mount partitions.